# Three.js metallic material

Tags: three.js

i'm trying to create a metallic material for my .obj model.
The model does not have the UVMap.
I've been trying since yesterday but nothing, it remains always one color and can't notice the edges.

Comment: For metalness, it's better to use `THREE.StandardMaterial()`, but it's hard to provide more help, having no code example of what you've tried.

Comment: i just need a well setted metallic material

Comment: Have a look at this [official example](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=materials#webgl_materials_variations_standard).